# cqlsh not working, getting "ImportError: cannot import name ensure_text"

Tags: cassandra

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh", line 7, in <module>
    from cqlsh.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlsh/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cqlsh.cqlsh import main as cqlsh_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlsh/cqlsh.py", line 131, in <module>
    from six import StringIO, ensure_text, ensure_str
ImportError: cannot import name ensure_text
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question is missing a few details. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) steps to replicate the problem. For guidance, see https://stackexchange.com/tour and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Without relevant details, it's impossible for us to provide you with a meaningful response.

All I can say is that I suspect you have an environmental issue where you have an old Python `six` library installed on your machine that doesn't have [the `ensure_str` and `ensure_text` functions added in v1.12.0](https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/1.12.0/CHANGES#L12-L13).

A friendly reminder that you need to provide details about your problem including:

- the cqlsh software version
- Cassandra version
- full error message + full stack trace
- steps to replicate the problem
- what investigation you've done
- whether you've done any research

If it helps, I've published an article on the Apache Cassandra website on [How to ask good questions](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community/ask_good_questions.html). Cheers!